# How to extract a column of a table from html page using perl modules?

Tags: perl, html-parsing, perl-module

I have the following html code of a part of a webpage.

```
<h2 id="failed_process">Failed Process</h2>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <b>pid</b>
      </th>
      <th>
        <b>Priority</b>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="90"><a href="details.jsp?pid=p_201211162334&refresh=0">p_201211162334</a></td>
      <td id="priority_90">NORMAL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="91"><a href="details.jsp?pid=p_201211163423&refresh=0">p_201211163423</a></td>
      <td id="priority_91">NORMAL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="98"><a href="details.jsp?pid=p_201211166543&refresh=0">p_201211166543</a></td>
      <td id="priority_98">NORMAL</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
```

I need to extract the pid column . The output should look like

```
pid
p_201211162334
p_201211163423
p_201211166543
```

The table count for "Failed Process" table is 4. But the problem is if I mention the table count as 4 and  if there are no failed tasks in the webpage, it'll go to the next table and fetch the pid's of next table resulting in wrong pid's.

I am using the below code to get the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict; 
 use warnings;
 use lib qw(..);
 use HTML::TableExtract;

 my $content = get("URL");
 my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new(
 headers => [qw(pid)], attribs => { id => 'failed_process' },
 );

 $te->parse($content);

 foreach my $col ($te->rows) {
 print ("\t", @$col), "\n";
 }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Can't call method "rows" on an undefined value
```

Comment: the `id => 'failed_process'` is not the id of the table, but the header

Comment: Yes!! How do i extract pid referring to that id of the header?

Comment: May be you need first get table and then get rows? Please look at examples of using module - http://search.cpan.org/~msisk/HTML-TableExtract-2.11/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm

Comment: KostiaShiian : I looked into the above mentioned link many times. It doesn't have the required details.. !!

Comment: Check out [Mojo::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-3.73/lib/Mojo/UserAgent.pm). It can be done quite easily with this module.

Comment: This would be much simpler to answer if we could see the full HTML page. Are you saying that the table is omitted altogether from the page if there are no failed processes? Is the subsequent table (the one after the failed processes table) always present? You have omitted the `<table>` element from your example; is it just a bare `<table>` or does it have any attributes?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice the opening `<table>` tag because it was after the `<h2>` element and on the same line. Please ignore that part of my comment. I have reformatted the HTML in your question for better clarity.

Comment: Yes. The whole table gets omitted from the page if there are no failed process and yes,the subsequent table is always present.i do have mentioned the <table> element in the code.
The table just have the h2 tag with its id and no other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

With my favourite DOM parser [Mojo::DOM](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM) from the [Mojolicious suite](http://mojolicio.us) it would look like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Mojo::DOM;

# instantiate with all DATA lines
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do { local $/; <DATA> });

# extract all first column cells
$dom->find('table tr')->each(sub {
    my $cell = shift->children->[0];
    say $cell->all_text;
});

__DATA__
<h2 id="failed_process">Failed Process</h2>
<table border="1">
    ...
```

Output:

```
pid
p_201211162334
p_201211163423
p_201211166543
```

Answer (score 0):

After `$te->parse($html)` you may add some like `foreach my $table ($te->tables) ..` then you can get rows `$table->rows`. You may also use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper) to analyze `$te`.

Comment: Hmmm..I Tried with the above changes.. Its not Working.. !!

Comment: Did you analyze output of Data::Dumper($te)?

Comment: yes i did.. this is the small snippet of the o/p
$VAR1 = bless( {'_ts_sequential' => [],
                 'headers' => ['pid'
                              ],
                 'br_translate' => 1,
                 'gridmap' => 1, 'attribs' => {
                                'id' => 'failed_process'
                              },
                 '_counts' => [
                                5,
                                3
                              ],
                 '_tablestack' => []
               }, 'HTML::TableExtract' );

Comment: This code works:

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Data::Dumper;


my $content;

open (F,'<' , $ARGV[0]);

while (<F>)
{
 $content.= $_;
}


 my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new(
 headers => [qw(pid)]
 );

 $te->parse($content);

my @table = $te->tables;

  foreach my $row ($table[0]->rows) 
 {
  print join(',', @$row), "\n"; 
}

Comment: Thanks Shiian!! But when I use this code directly with the URL, it doesn't work!!

Comment: $content must contains html code. You need check it. And I don`t inderstand what is get? Do you use LWP::Simple?